# Match a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I wish to chop some text into sentences.

I wish to match all text up until: a period followed by a space, a question mark followed by a space or an exclamation mark followed by a space, in an non greedy fashion.

Additionally, the punctuation might be found at the very end of the string or followed by a /r/n for example.

This will almost do it:

```
([^\.\?\!]*)
```

But I'm missing the space in the expression. How do I fix this?

**Example:**

`I' a.m not. So? Sure about this! Actually.` Should give:

```
I' a.m not
So
Sure about this
Actually
```

Comment: what language are you working in?

Comment: It's funny how people are crafting answer as fast as possible while the question itself was not quite clear enough. haha

Comment: In that case, the answer by @stema is the best. Accept that answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve such conditions by using [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
[^.?!]+(?=[.?!] )
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36g0k).

When you look at the demo, The sentences at the end of a row with no following space are not matched. You can fix this by adding an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with the [Anchor `$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and using the modifier `m` (makes the `$` match the end of a row):

```
[^.?!]+(?=[.?!](?: |$))
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36g0q)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`(.*?[!\.\?] )`

.* gives all,

[] is any of these characters

then the () gives you a group to reference so you can get the match out.

Comment: Because your question was not very specific. Your initial question was to match everything until a period, question mark, or exclamation mark, _followed by space_

Comment: My mistake - the first problem with it is that it needs a ? to make the .* lazy (first match). Now, if you are using this in code what I would do is loop, so call that - then strip out the sentence and call it again on the resulting text.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-greedy match with s look ahead:

```
^.*?(?=[.!?]( |$))
```

Note how you don't have to escape those chars when they are in a character class `[...]`.

Comment: This is it! But hmm, OP says that there might even be no punctuation at the very end at all.

Comment: @justhalf you're right - I've now catered for a space *or* end of input after the full stop.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
^.*?(?=[!.?][\s])
```

Comment: will `\s` match the end of line?

Comment: yes, that matches any whitespace character.  you could be more specific and match just a single space.